# How to change date and time format from"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" to "h:mm a"?

Tags: java, date, datetime

I am using below code to format data and time as time.But it does not work can anyone help me how to fix this problem.

```
 try {
         String actualDate = m.getDate();//get date as"28-aug-2015 6:46:32 pm"
         Date Date= new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss").parse(actualDate);
         convertDate = new SimpleDateFormat("h:mm a").format(Date);//6:46 am  
    }
    catch (ParseException e) {

         e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

after converting the format i got my "convertDate" value as "6.46 am" but now time is "6:46 pm" how can i fix this problem.

Comment: FYI, the terribly troublesome date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html) classes built into Java 8 and later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have some bugs there, this is what you want:

```
Date date= new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss").parse(actualDate);
convertDate = new SimpleDateFormat("H:mm").format(date);
```

If you use am/pm then:

```
Date date= new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy h:mm:ss a").parse(actualDate);
convertDate = new SimpleDateFormat("h:mm a").format(date);
```

Comment: can you please add the code for mention the current time is am/pm?

Comment: Am/pm is "a" but then you should use "h" instead of "H". All the details are here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Comment: i was edited my code now the time displayed as "6.58 am" but it should be displayed as"6.58 pm" where i am  getting mistake please explain.

Comment: If you use am/pm on input and output your code should be:
Date date= new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy h:mm:ss a").parse(actualDate);
String convertDate = new SimpleDateFormat("h:mm a").format(date);

Answer (score 0):

## java.time

The modern approach uses the *java.time* classes.

We use a builder to flag our formatter as being case-insensitive with regard to the spelling of the your month name and your AM/PM that ignore the cultural norms of US English.

```
    String input = "28-aug-2015 6:46:32 pm";

    DateTimeFormatterBuilder builder = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder();
    builder.parseCaseInsensitive();
    builder.appendPattern( "dd-MMM-uuuu h:m:s a" );
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = builder.toFormatter().withLocale( Locale.US) ;

    LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse( input , formatter );
```

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/arvDzw).

> input: 28-aug-2015 6:46:32 pm
>
> ldt.toString(): 2015-08-28T18:46:32

### Automatically localize

If your input meets the cultural norms of some particular locale, use `DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDateTime` instead of this builder approach.

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

[image: Table of which java.time library to use with which version of Java or Android]

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).